# Identify this famous instrumental music played on the electric harp

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

At the end of the following interview (2:30), Enki Bello starts playing a piece of music:
[Enki Bello TV NBC "Telemundo New York" Interview](https://youtu.be/nimaZ_V7vjM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is

> Shakira - [Hips don't lie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUT5rEU6pqM)